# How to make Stove Fire?

Tags: animation, materials, node-editor, smoke-simulation, fire

how are you? So, I'm going to create and Stove animation and I wanted to know how can I make a Stove fire with Fire Simulation in Blender. I have seen lots of tutos on fire, but they are all the same with big fires. Is there a way to make the fire more smooth and consistent, and also blue?

Kind regards.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far, and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: I just created some fires following the tutorials online, which means they were always big fires. Didn't really try to make one small and blue and with little movement. That's pretty much what I don't know how to do. How can I make a fire that doesn't move much and how to turn it blue?